# Map webjar path in html files to load dependencies

Tags: angularjs, dropwizard, webjars

I am using dropwizard along with webjars to package my web dependencies. Relatively new to using dropwizard.

In my initialize() method in the Bootstrap application, I am loading my asset and web bundles as below

```
 bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/webapp", "/ui", "index.html"));
 bootstrap.addBundle(new WebJarBundle("org.webjars.bower", "org.webjars"));
```

In my index.html file I refer to my js dependencies as below

```
<!-- Third Party -->
<script src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/lodash/dist/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/tether/tether.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/devextreme/js/dx.all.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>
<!-- App Configuration -->
<script src="ui/app/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="ui/app/app.routing.js"></script>
<script src="ui/app/app.constants.js"></script>
<script src="ui/app/app.run.js"></script>
```

1. How do I find out the exact path to provide in index.html to refer to the js files. I tried unzipping the dependency jars but could not find any information to identify the path. For example angular-ui-router is under release folder while the other js files aren't.
2. I have included bootstrap version 4.0.0-alpha.6-1 and that required tether which I have also include in my pom.xml . I presume I am not referring the path for tether.js correctly in index.html. I see both the dependencies available in my fat jar. What should be the correct path, may be answer to #1 will help me resolve this question.

> ```
> org.webjars tether 1.4.0 
> org.webjars bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6-1
> ```

```
**Error**

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)
    at bootstrap.js:2749
    at bootstrap.js:3350
    at bootstrap.js:3535
```